# Windows time command equivalent

Tags: linux, windows, central-processing-unit, time, utilization

There is a command in Linux that outputs system utilization called time. Is there a Windows equivalent? Or how else can I manually use the task manager commands in a batch file?

Comment: Do you mean `uptime`?  The `time` command simply benchmarks how long it takes to run a command.

Comment: No time is what I need. I want to benchmark how long it takes to run the command but I want to do it on Windows so I can do it in a batch file.

Answer (score 2):

If your Operating System has powershell (older operating systems might need a download), you can simply use Measure-Command cmdlet.

Comment: Ok is there one to measure cpu utilization? Not just time but utilization as well

Answer (score 2):

The Windows Server 2003 Resource kit includes a timeit utility. The resource kit works fine on XP as well, and I've used the individual tools on newer Windows operating systems as well.

Comment: Ok is there one to measure cpu utilization? Not just time but utilization as well.

Comment: not directly i know of, but process explorer may fit your requirements. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653

Comment: I need a way to do it from the command prompt because eventually i need to do it in a batch script.

Comment: again in powershell, you can do: (get-process processname).cpu, where processname is the name of the process. this is only a snapshot at the tiem so you need to do some sort of summing/averaging etc. yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I found a tool which -- while not a direct port -- appears to give you the information you desire.

```
C:\> timemem "find \"e\" myfile.txt"

---------- MYFILE.TXT
>ONE Homo sapiens alu
>TWO IUB ambiguity codes
>THREE Homo sapiens frequency

Process ID: 476
    elapsed time (seconds): 5.81
    user time (seconds): 0.55
    kernel time (seconds): 0.30
    Page Fault Count: 3150
    Peak Working Set Size (kbytes): 12420
    Quota Peak Paged Pool Usage: 78324
    Quota Peak Non Paged Pool Usage: 2240
    Peak Pagefile Usage: 917504
```

timemem.exe is available from [Andy Fingerhut's page of code](http://homepage.mac.com/jafingerhut/files/code/code.html) and the timemem source is hosted on github as part of [the clojure-benchmark repo](https://github.com/jafingerhut/clojure-benchmarks/).

Much detail is available in [readme-timemem.txt](https://raw.github.com/jafingerhut/clojure-benchmarks/master/bin/readme-timemem.txt), form where I copied the above example.

(found from [this neglected answer over on superuser](https://superuser.com/a/205694/9465))